# CMake FIND_LIBRARY() ignores library's OUTPUT_NAME

Tags: cmake

Due to naming conflict, I am adding a prefix to all the PCL libraries (http://pointclouds.org/). I am doing this via setting the property OUTPUT_NAME (https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/set_target_properties.html). Here's an example:

```
PCL_ADD_LIBRARY("${LIB_NAME}" "${SUBSYS_NAME}" ${srcs})
SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES("${LIB_NAME}" PROPERTIES OUTPUT_NAME "ii3d_${LIB_NAME}")
```

Note that `PCL_ADD_LIBRARY()` macro uses `ADD_LIBRARY()` within it.

Above is working well. Instead of creating pcl_common_release.lib and pcl_common_release.dll, it is creating ii3d_pcl_common_release.lib and ii3d_pcl_common_release.dll. This is what I want.

The problem comes when another library wants to use the above libraries. Currently PCLConfig.cmake has

```
find_library(PCL_${COMPONENT}_LIBRARY ${pcl_component}${PCL_RELEASE_SUFFIX}
  HINTS ${PCL_LIBRARY_DIRS}
  DOC "path to ${pcl_component} library"
  NO_DEFAULT_PATH)
```

It is returning the absolute path of the library without the "ii3d_" prefix. This file doesn't even exist. As an example, it is returning `E:/libs/pcl/builds/win64-shared-release-cl-qt/lib/pcl_common_release.lib`. It should be returning `E:/libs/pcl/builds/win64-shared-release-cl-qt/lib/ii3d_pcl_common_release.lib` instead.

I even tried adding "ii3d_" prefix inside `FIND_LIBRARY()` as shown below:

```
find_library(PCL_${COMPONENT}_LIBRARY 
  "ii3d_${pcl_component}${PCL_RELEASE_SUFFIX}"
  HINTS ${PCL_LIBRARY_DIRS}
  DOC "path to ${pcl_component} library"
  NO_DEFAULT_PATH)
```

But even this returns the absolute path of the library without the prefix "ii3d_".

Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: 'But even this returns the absolute path of the library without the prefix "ii3d_".' - `find_library` should return a library with a requested name. Make sure that you have cleared cache variables after changing `PCLConfig.cmake` script.

Comment: Thanks @Tsyvarev, clearing cache worked!